# How to round float in c#

Tags: c#, string, optimization, rounding

I want to get number, which  .ToString() conversion total lenght <= 7. For example

```
 1. 1.23456789     - > 1.23457 
 2. 12345.789      - > 12345.8
 3. 123456789.1234 - > 1.235E8
 4. 0.00001234 - > 1.23E-8
```

I want to use realy fast solution, because work with big file.

This code can solve part of this problem, but it dont work

```
                    int power = (int)Math.Log10(f) + 1;
                    f = f / (float)Math.Pow(10, power);
                    f = (float)Math.Round(f, 5);
                    f = f * (float)Math.Pow(10, power);
```

For example
`f  = 7.174593E+10`
after rounding it become `0.71746` (fine for me)

and when i multiplie it by `10^11` it become `7.17459948E+10`

but i expected `7.71746E+10`

UPD.
As result i want to get string, not a number.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to understand more about how binary floating point numbers are represented. To take a trivial example, 0.1 can't be exactly represented as a `float`. You should probably consider what you want the underlying value to be vs how you want to represent it in text for display etc.

Comment: Would `String.format("{f:0.00000}",f)` be of use? (could be that it needs to be 0,00000 depending on the region settings).

Comment: Why do you need such formatting for a number? Do you only want to output the resukt in any form (than `String.Format` will be your friend), or do you need the result for further computations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are going to use it for is to display it as string (as said in the update) then use `String.format()`.

```
//one of these should output it correctly the other uses the wrong character as
//decimal seperator (depends on globalization settings)
String.format("{0:0,00000}",f);//comma for decimal
String.format("{0:0.00000}",f);//point for decimal
//how it works: first you say {0} meaning first variable after the text " "
//then you specify the notation :0,00000 meaning 1 number before the seperator at least
// and 5 numbers after.
```

Example

```
f = 0,123456789
String.format("Text before the number {0:0.00000} Text after the number",f);
//output:
//Text before the number 0,12345 Text after the number

//input: 123456789.1234
textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:0,0##E0}", f); 
//output: 1.235E5
```

Comment: What about this conversion
123456789.1234 - > 1.235E8 
?

Comment: with a little google I found this `     textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:E2}", f); ` it will go to 1.23E008 that way, i dont know why the 0's before the 8 but I think that if you search for `string.format` on google you can find the right format code.

Comment: @virty Thought I'd look for it as well and found it really quickly ill add it to the awnser

Answer (score 4):

If you want to round in order to use it later in calculations, use Math.Round((decimal)myDouble, 3).

If you don't intend to use it in calculation but need to display it, use double.ToString("F3").